# Displaying submenus on hover without javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that uses jquery to display a submenu div while a user is hovering over an a:link in the main parent menu.

```
$('.menu ul li').hover(function() { 
    $(this).find('.dropnav').stop(true, true).fadeTo('fast', 1); 
}, function() { 
    $(this).find('.dropnav').stop(true, true).fadeOut(800, 0); 
});
```

The problem is, I want this webpage's navigation feature to be independent of javascript. So when users do not have javascript enabled, the menu will still display - just without the effects of scrolls or fades.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an old article but still applicable here - http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class.

```
.menu ul li:hover .dropnav {
    opacity: 1;
    /* display: block; ? */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty solid example of a CSS based menu. There is JavaScript that goes with it, if you are looking for backwards compatibility to IE6.

http://qrayg.com/learn/code/cssmenus/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#">main nav-1</a>        
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">main nav-2</a>       
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">sub-nav-2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub-nav-2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">sub-nav-2.3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
     <li><a href="#">main nav-3</a>
     <li><a href="#">main nav-4</a>   
    </ul>
```

**css**

```
ul.main-nav > li { position: relative; display: block; float: left;  margin: 0 15px;}
ul.main-nav > li > a {display: block; line-height: 40px; }
ul.sub-nav { display:none; position: absolute; top: 40px; left: 0; min-width: 200px;}
ul.main-nav > li:hover ul.sub-nav { display: block; z-index: 999; }
```

check this one for live demo http://jsfiddle.net/q9YZf/

Comment: for more complex structure and more info check this URL
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/?search_index=28