# Display element by hovering without javascript

Tags: html, css

I'd like to prevent jquery in some stuff I do and therefore stumbled upon this article here: [Displaying submenus on hover without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311636/displaying-submenus-on-hover-without-javascript)

So, I tried to implement it with a very simple test like that:

```
<div class="trigger-hover">Hover this</div>
<div class="target-hover">Supersecret content</div>
```

and the css therefore like this:

```
.target-hover{
    display:none;
    background:red;
    padding:300px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.trigger-hover:hover div.target-hover{
display:block;
}
```

But this just doesn't do anything on my side. What is the trick with it? Does the target that shall get displayed be nested into the triggering element? Is it something in the syntax?

Thanks

Comment: `a b` is "given an element a, do something to its child b`. your html isn't a parent/child situation. it's siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.trigger-hover:hover div.target-hover {...}` would show a `.target-hover` *within* `.trigger-hover`, whereas your `div`s are adjacent. You'll want to use:

```
.trigger-hover:hover + .target-hover {
   display:block;
}
```

To show the adjacent `div`

```css
.target-hover {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.trigger-hover:hover + .target-hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger-hover">Hover this</div>
<div class="target-hover">Supersecret content</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Where is the difference between the "~"-operator from the first answer and the "+"-operator in your answer - could you roughly point me to which does make sense when? Just wondering because both work the same here

Comment: @Daiaiai [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) is a very helpful article for css selectors, read throught it.

Comment: `~` will find all following siblings that match the selector. `+` will only match the *very next* element.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.target-hover {
    display: none;
}
.trigger-hover:hover ~.target-hover{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger-hover">Hover this</div>
<div class="target-hover">Supersecret content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger-hover:hover div.target-hover` means that `target-hover` div is inside `trigger-hover div`, but in your html they are one after another.